# Python classes and objects

Tags: python

I am a bit new to Oops and I am getting confused with Python classes.Though I studied C++ in high school, but I know what I studied back then wasn't C++ at all(It was kind of C with classes, no templates, STL, or namespace)

Correct me if I am wrong, but for me classes are just blueprints for objects, right?

Now if I wanted to create an instance of a class in C++(For eg, my class name is "animal")

I would do this:
`animal lion;`
or if I had a constructor(with arguments) then only I would do this`animal tiger(4,5);`

The problem I am facing is:

```
class animal:
    val = 5
```

Its just a basic class, without any constuctor or methods:

Now with python I am able to reference animal as it is without creating any instances of it(I coudn't do that in C++, right?)

```
animal.val = 7
```

Another problem I am facing is,I need to use parenthesis always while creating instances, or it will refer to the class itself.

For eg;

```
lion = animal
lion.val = 6
tiger = animal
print tiger.val
```

and it prints 6,when I want to create an instance I've to use paranthesis, even though I haven't specified any constructor(Which wasn't necessary in C++), any special reason or just a matter of language syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything in Python is an object. *Classes are objects that create other objects.*

Thus, when you reference `animal.val`, you're referencing the *class* property `val` on the *class* `animal`.

If you want to actually create an object of type `animal`, you'd call the class and get an instance back:

```
your_animal = animal()
```

Anything you set on that instance is then set for only that instance (whereas changes to the class are shared among all objects created via the class).

See [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) for more details about classes in Python.

Comment: so using parenthesis is in fact just a language syntax, and doesn't refer to anything specific?

Comment: But then if I don't have a constructor, why do is still need the parenthesis?

Comment: @KartikAnand: You do have a constructor, you just didn't write it yourself.

Comment: @wooble so like in C++, if I specify my own constructor, will the default one get hidden as well?

Comment: The constructor is the `__new__()` method, and you almost never need to override it. You probably want to define `__init__` to initialize instances in most cases. This is all covered by any python tutorial.

Comment: @Wooble yes I was reading that only but got confused while comparing it will C++

Answer (score 2):

> Now with python I am able to reference animal as it is without
>   creating any instances of it(I coudn't do that in C++, right?)

You have declared a static variable.  As you can see it can get a little confusing without keywords.  What you have done is the same as `static` in c++ classes

To create an instance variable it needs to be explicitly assigned to instance.

```
class animal:     
  def __init__(self):
     self.val = 0


your_animal = animal()
your_animal.val = 3
```

`animal.val` is no longer globally available.

Answer (score 2):

To show analogy to C++ (btw it's good practice to declare clases with Capital name, to distinguish class from member which is by convetion in lower case):

```
class Animal:
  val = 4 # class variable

  def __init__ (self, val = 0): # constructor (takes 0 or 1 argument)
    self.member_val = val # instance variable
```

You call `animal = Animal(5)` to create new instance. Watch how `Animal.val` and `animal.val` differs:

```
animal = Animal(5)
print Animal.val, animal.member_val
>>> 4 5
```

Equivalent code in C++ would be:

```
class Animal {
  public:
    Animal() { // constructor with no arguments
       this.member_val = 0;
    }

    Animal(int val) { // constructor with argument
      this.member_val = val;
    }

  public:
    int member_val; // member (instance) variable allocated for each instance
    static int val = 4; // class level static variable
}
```

And class usage:

```
Animal animal = new Animal(5);
cout << Animal.val << " " << animal.member_val

>>> 5 4
```

Comment: Thanks your analogy to C++ did help me with some of my queries